# How do we calculate Big O when an operation used has multiple possible algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

When calculating the Big O for a section of code how does one handle the situation where an operation used in the code segment could have a different number of operations based on the algorithm used?

To clarify my question I'm first going to use a blatantly stupid example to clearly show the issue and then describe a more reasonable but not as clear example.

**Very Simple Example:**

Lets say your trying to calculate the Big O value for

```
import Calculator # Third party library
total = 0
b = 7
for a in list_of_As:
    total += Calculator.multiply(a, b)
```

Now we know nothing about how `Calculator.multiply` goes about to get its result.

Our code could have `O(n)` if `Calculator.multiply` was defined by

```
def multiply(a, b) :
    return a * b
```

or our code could have `O(n^2)` if `Calculator.multiply` was very inefficient and was defined by

```
def multiply(a, b):
    rtn = 0
    for i in range(b):
        rtn += a
```

**More reasonable example**

In machine learning, there are many different third-party libraries available to help speed up development. How does one go about determining the Big O of a machine-learning solution we designed when we don't know the algorithms or the Big O of the third-party methods used within it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the complexity of an algorithm depends on the complexity of one (or more) of its operations, and the complexity of that operation is not necessarily known, there are a couple of ways you can describe it:

- Give the complexity of the number of operations. For example, optimal sorting algorithms are often described as O(*n* log *n*) time, but it's a little bit more accurate to say that they perform O(*n* log *n*) comparison operations. The complexity of a comparison operation typically does not depend on the length of the list, but it may depend on the input in some other way, e.g. it takes O(*c*) time in the worst case to compare strings of length *c*.
- Use a generic term such as *f*(*n*) for the complexity of the relevant operation, rather than a concrete term such as *n*<sup>2.373</sup>.

Applying these options to your calculator example, we could say either that the algorithm performs O(*n*) multiplications, or that its time complexity is O(*n* *f*(*n*)) where *f*(*n*) is the time complexity of multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

The question is how to empirically guess the big-O based on some sample runs.

The answer is to put it on a [log-log plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot).

If it looks roughly like a line with slope `k`, then it probably has a big-O of roughly the form `O(n^k)`.  This is imprecise and it is easy to come up with counterexamples. But in practice it tends to work well.

The main thing that goes wrong is that the big-O is dominated by a small but rapidly growing term.  So it looks like one pattern until that term becomes big enough, then it looks like a different pattern.  See [Accidentally Quadratic](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/) for a number of real life examples.